# Update UI after app is created

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, updates, imagebutton

I am developing an Android app that has scrollview and imagebuttons in its main layout. I use images from drawable folder and call them by their ids.

```
//AboutScreen.java class
    private ImageButton mStartButton3;

    mStartButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.woops3); 

    mStartButton3.setOnClickListener(this);


//MainLayout.xml
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/woops3"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/woops6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/button_start"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_title" />
```

But i want to update these images (imagebuttons) by images that i download from a json webservice during splashscreen.

Can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go for this :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{ 

Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("Your URL");

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagefromserver);

img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}


private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) 
    throws IOException

 {

 InputStream in = null;

        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString); 
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect(); 

            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
            }                     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
        }
        return in;     
    }
    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {        
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;        
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;                
    }
```